# what happen if a high voltage connects to pc-based oscilloscope's ground?

Tags: circuit-design, oscilloscope, opto-isolator, isolation, circuit-protection

What happens if a high voltage (for example 500V) is connected to PC-based oscilloscope's ground?

In principle, nothing should happen, but if somehow the PC's ground and high voltage's reference tied together (through home wiring or etc) this looks like
ground loop problem in oscilloscope.

Will the PC be damaged? If the answer is yes, how did PC-based oscilloscopes solve this problem? Can you suggest any circuit to fix this problem? I want to design a channel 200Msa/s 50 MHz bandwidth PC-based oscilloscope.

------------- Update

my circuit is like this: 
[image]
I'm using LMH6702 instead of AD8021. I'll sample from signal with ADC8200(8 bit 200Mega sample ADC) and ... Finally, the data is transferred to the computer by cy68013 the circuit works fine but as i said i dont know how can i eliminate the problem i said

Comment: How can you design one if you dont understand all the implications of high voltage, BVD protection to CM input range with variable attenuators and gain  and screen sync trigger latency at 60 frames per second? 100MHz BW stripline and 50 MHz Nyquist filter  . Keep researching to find a hundred other Questions you must understand before you can think of a design.

Comment: It might go poof or be very noisy.

Comment: that's why wifi makes sense for some unexpected things

Comment: use optical isolators between the ADC and your computer. run your circuit and the ADC on batteries.

Comment: @jsotola because sampling speed is amlost high(200M) i couldn't find any opto isolator that work for me

Answer (score 2):

You must assume that at some point high voltage will be placed on your "scope module" incorrectly and design it so the user is safe according to for instance Low Voltage Directive (LVD) 2014/35/EU. You will never get certification unless stringent rules are followed depending on where your market will be. As for connecting to a PC you will want to use optical isolation to relay the data back and forth with optimally no electrical connection between the two at all. Depending on the marketing area you will want to review government mandated requirements. This can get real Hairy my friend!

Comment: As an alternative to optical isolation, Silicon Laboratories makes some pretty good capacitive multi-channel digital isolators that will get up to 100Mbps.

Comment: yes but my sampling speed is 200M and i couldnt find any opto isolator thaht work for me

Comment: @amin5659 you are looking for high bandwidth network isolation. By default ethernet ports have that.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to where is your 500V isolation?

( don't rely on your laptop charger. they are notoriously noisy on high impedance probes)

Where is your 240V/50Hz CM hum reduction? What is your noise spec?

Does that voltage isolation also attenuate SMPS noise or make it worse with Y cap ground shunt current? or worse it has none and the ferrite leakage capacitance transfers SMPS noise to the secondary DC... that becomes common mode noise.

Is there CM noise interference onto high impedance inputs with say 10pF transformer leakage at 100KHz creating 1MHz harmonics so the cap now looks like 10KΩ @1MHz as common mode noise into a 10 MΩ input probe?

What about 5kV ESD protection?  What about input capacitance loading?

You need a probe that has input a breakdown >500V and protected against 15kV ESD or even 5kV.  Is it possible yes. Will the clamp be faster than blowing your front end? Maybe not !  Will it have enough CMRR at the SMPS clock rate of harmonics.   Will it have  or need 80 dB CMRR at 1MHz ? It must be very well balanced , have extremely low input capacitance and exceptionally wide bandwidth to show a 50MHz square wave ( > 250MHz) 
.... because you're not bleepin' likely to get that from any Op Amp.

**Maybe you want to use 16 bit sigma delta ADC with an opto-isolator.**

Search my other answers on 50MHz probe design.

**If you have any dreams** of commercializing this design , take heed with @Thomas Z.'s direction and document the design specs and test verification results *as well as your favorite instrument brand marketting spec* but consider an external PS that is already qualified and is low noise.

**More important** is how will you design the PLL with variable holdoff for frame rate sync to your signal for a steady display under all conditions of noise glitches?  Or how will you select a trigger to catch those one in a million glitches?

Comment: hi thanks for your response. I do not think you understood me. i've design and build this scope but without any protection.

Comment: can you take a look to my circuit and make a suggestion for protection?!

Comment: @amin5659 if you have a schematic that you would like people to look at, then please add it into your question. I don't believe that you can upload it directly with low rep, but can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @ Daniel Giesbrecht hi i attach the schematic

Comment: @amin5659  Your isolation depends purely on the AC-DC converter +/-5V. But your input impedance is terrible.  ~est -j500 Ohms at 50MHz , so dependant on source impedance and not 1MOhm flat as you might think, unless that was intentional.  Now your smaller probe caps must also be rated for 500V

Comment: Try a 10MHz square wave or a 50MHz sine  with 500R source  and  note the 50% error

Comment: of course. the equivalent input impedance is about 1mega ohm with 20 pf parallel capacitor.this is like other oscilloscopes.the parallel capacitance can be decreased but it will never be zero.(typical input impedance is 1Mega ohm with 10-20 pf parallel capacitance)

Comment: You could scale the C's all down by 10  with care. or even better eliminate the high offset JFETS and rely on just a R ratio to 900K,100K since 10:1 must compensate for cable capacitance and if your buffer is in the probe, you wont need this since the LMH6702 is only 1.7pF. Keep in mind with coax capacitance you get a 10~20MHz resonance with any long coax and long probe ground lead to the front end. So the probe amp fails to deliver flat response.

Answer (score -1):

If the high voltage is not referenced to ground, for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv922H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then you are fine. (Notice how the voltage source's negative is not connected to ground). However, if you ground the other end of the voltage source, bad things will happen. Hopefully you'll have some protection diodes and a fuse in the frontend, in which case the fuse will blow, otherwise your oscilloscope is fried.

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you take a look to my circuit?

Comment: How is this supposed to take a reading without a complete circuit? Try connecting replacing the TL081 with your multimeter on DC volts, connect one probe to ground and the other to one terminal of a battery (replacing the 500 V source). Report back with the voltage reading obtained.

Comment: This is the entire point. It's perfectly fine to connect 500V to the input, provided that it's not referenced to the oscilloscope ground. Otherwise you let the magic smoke out

Comment: so how can i eliminate this problem?